# Spring ClassPathXmlApplicationContext data connection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, connection

I'm trying create a connection using Spring 3.2.0 but I get NullPointerException of:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("conexao/conexao.xml")
```

my file conexao.xml is in `conexao` package. And my xml file is configured as presented:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="banco" class="modelo.Banco">
        <property name="usuario">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
        <property name="senha">
            <value>""</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agenda</value>
        </property>
        <property name="classForName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It always stop at this like when debugging:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("conexao/conexao.xml")
```

my code:

```
package dao;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import model.Banco;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Conexao {

    private static Banco banco;

    private static Conexao instance;

    public static Conexao getInstance() {
        if (Conexao.instance == null) {
            Conexao.instance = new Conexao();
        }
        return Conexao.instance;

    }

    private Conexao() {

    }

    public Connection abrirConexao() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "conexao/conexao.xml");
        Connection con = null;
        banco = (Banco) ctx.getBean("Banco");
        try {
            Class.forName(banco.getClassForName()); // Carrega o driver
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(banco.getUrl(),
                    banco.getUsuario(), banco.getSenha()); // obtem a conexao
                                                            // com o banco
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return con;
    }

    public Statement getStatement() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return abrirConexao().createStatement();
    }

    public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql)
            throws InterruptedException {

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = this.abrirConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Erro com a conexao. Verifique se sua conexao esta ativa.");
        }
        return ps;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the Exception ? Please add the stacktrace

Comment: Do you get NPE when creating context? Also captalization matters, Banko != banko.

Comment: The exception is NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see your class name are different:

```
import model.Banco;
```

and in the xml configuration you have:

```
<bean id="banco" class="modelo.Banco">
```

you could change xml file to `model.Banco` to correct this problem.

Another point already commented by Ivan is the case sensitive names. Since you are requesting bean with name `Banco` you need to change your bean id to `Banco` too.

```
banco = (Banco) ctx.getBean("Banco"); // here your request it with upper B
```

and declaration is:

```
<bean id="banco" class="modelo.Banco">
```

Try to change just your XML to:

```
<bean id="Banco" class="modelo.Banco">
```

Comment: pasting the stack trace might help.

Comment: The answer was edited and added the case sensitive issue. Please change XML bean id from `banco` to `Banco`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this way

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:conexao/conexao.xml");
```